# SQLite UPDATE returns empty

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to update a table column from another table with the code below.
Now the editor says '39 rows affected' and I can see something happened because some cells changed from *null* to empty  (nothing shows).
While orhers are still *null*

What could be wrong here?
Why does it not update properly....

PS: I checked manually that the values are not empty in the column to check for.

```
UPDATE CANZ_CONC
SET EAN = (SELECT t1.EAN_nummer FROM ArtLev_CONC t1 WHERE t1.Artikelcode_leverancier = Artikelcode_leverancier)
WHERE ARTNMR IN (SELECT t1.Artikelcode_leverancier FROM Artlev_CONC t1 WHERE t1.Artikelcode_leverancier = ARTNMR);
```

Edit:

The tabel2 is like:

```
NMR | EAN | CUSTOM
-------------------------------
1       | 987 | A
2       | 654 | B
3       | 321 | C
```

Tabel 1 is like

```
NMR | EAN | CUSTOM
-------------------------------
1       | null |  null 
2       | null |  null 
5       | null |  null
```

After the UPDATE table1 is like

```
NMR | EAN | CUSTOM
-------------------------------
1       |        |  null 
2       |        |  null 
5       | null |  null
```

Comment: So the data changes correctly? An UPDATE query should not give you any result on success.
Depending on what Library you are using to connect to sqlite there are different ways to get an affected rows count.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. 

The tabel2 is like:
`NMR | EAN | CUSTOM
-------------------------------
1       | 987 | A
2       | 654 | B
3       | 321 | C
`

Tabel 1 is like
`NMR | EAN | CUSTOM
-------------------------------
1       | null |  null 
2       | null |  null 
5       | null |  null 
`

After the UPDATE table1 is like
`NMR | EAN | CUSTOM
-------------------------------
1       |        |  null 
2       |        |  null 
5       | null |  null
`

Comment: Can you use the same table and field names between your code and example tables? Neither `Artikelcode_leverancier` nor `ARTNMR` are shown in the example tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working.
I guess my data was corrupted after all.
Since it is about 330.000 rows it was not very easy to spot.
But it came to me when the loading of the data took about 10 minutes!
It used to be about 40 - 60 seconds.

So I ended up back at the drawing board for the initial csv file.

I also saw the columns had not been given a DATA type, so I altered that as well.

Thanx for the help!